# How can I rewrite the following url http://domain.com/index.php?page=brand&brand_id=1

Tags: hyperlink, url-rewriting

*Hello everyone !

How can I rewrite the following url http://domain.com/index.php?page=brand&brand_id=1.
I want it to be displayed as domain.com/brand/1*

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad and there could be a number of different answers.  However, you could use a .htaccess file and write a rewrite rule:

https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString

Additionally, if you are using a PHP framework, or something similar, there may be a way to manipulate routes from with the code in a quite straightforward manner.

For example, CakePHP 3 has a routes.php file in which you can set up very straight forward url rewrites:

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html

It really depends on what you're set up is, though a .htaccess rewrite would be a safe bet either way.

Comment: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       Options +FollowSymLinks
       RewriteEngine On

       RewriteRule ^main/?$ index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^telefonal\.az [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.telefonal.az/$1 [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1


 </IfModule>`        HERE is .htaccess file

Comment: Add the following lines to .htaccess:

`RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?page=$1&brand_id=$2 [L]`

Something like that should work for you.  Don't forget to mark the question as correct if you get it working thanks to this =D

Comment: That should rewrite the URL to [http://domain.com/brand/1](http://domain.com/brand/1) might need to be tweak but try it out!